# MySQL STR_TO_DATE Problem while using this function

Tags: mysql, sql

As title, I'm trying to convert a **VARCHAR** column in a **DATE** column, and data is populated in that format **"DDMMYYYY"** ex. XMAS is "**25122022"** and in this case the correct formula should be **STR_TO_DATE(column, '%d%m%Y')**

Well, when I execute this query I get an error since in some cases I have values with a "missing" char, I mean, for example, **"1012023"** when the day is **<10** the query fails, cause it checks for **"01122023"** instead.

I could solve this easily **by adding a 0** to all fields having **length 7**, but I'd like to make it more clean.

Reading better the usage of **STR_TO_DATE** I noticed that I could replace %d with %e since the second choice should theorically consider days from **0 to 31 instead of 01 to 31**.

Unexpectedly the query didn't work and gave me the same erorr at the first instance of a **length 7 string**.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try left padding your date string with zero to a length of 8:

```sql
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '1012023' AS dt
)

SELECT STR_TO_DATE(LPAD(dt, 8, '0'), '%d%m%Y') AS dt_out  -- 2023-01-01
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: As long as there is no similar problem with the month part of the data

Comment: @Shadow Correct, but if both day and month could be missing digits then it may not be possible to remedy.

Comment: And I think this is a quite important caveat that should be part of the answer!

Comment: I solved using LPAD that's a bit better on B-Plan I thought (to put a "0" at the beginning for all strings length<8, but LPAD automatically do it without need to write an IF statement)